# CorePlot linker errors after upgrading iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, core-plot

This seems like it's happened before but somehow ended up working itself out.  It's happened again and I can't seem to get this fixed.  I use the CorePlot Cocoa Touch framework.  Everything was fine until I upgraded to the new 4.3 beta.  Now my project won't compile, and is giving me linker errors for unknown symbols having to do with CorePlot.  I've become a pro at adding the framework to my project, and I've checked and rechecked the instructions trying to do it again.

Is there a button I can click or anything to just make this work again?

I've used [these instructions](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications) to try to re-add the framework, to no avail

EDIT:  By the way, this compiles just fine for simulator and runs graphs no problem.  Compiling for the device gives me the linker errors, as follows:

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPPlotRange", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref in GraphStatsWindow.o


  objc-class-ref in iPadGraphView.o


  objc-class-ref in GraphTrendView.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPXYGraph", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref in GraphStatsWindow.o


  objc-class-ref in iPadGraphView.o


  objc-class-ref in GraphTrendView.o


   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTextStyle", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref in GraphStatsWindow.o


  objc-class-ref in iPadGraphView.o


  objc-class-ref in GraphTrendView.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPLineStyle", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref in GraphStatsWindow.o


  objc-class-ref in iPadGraphView.o


  objc-class-ref in GraphTrendView.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPScatterPlot", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref in GraphStatsWindow.o


  objc-class-ref in iPadGraphView.o


  objc-class-ref in GraphTrendView.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPAxisLabel", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref in GraphStatsWindow.o


  objc-class-ref in iPadGraphView.o


  objc-class-ref in GraphTrendView.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPPlotSymbol", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref in GraphStatsWindow.o


  objc-class-ref in iPadGraphView.o


  objc-class-ref in GraphTrendView.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPColor", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref in GraphStatsWindow.o


  objc-class-ref in iPadGraphView.o


  objc-class-ref in GraphTrendView.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPFill", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref in GraphStatsWindow.o


  objc-class-ref in iPadGraphView.o


  objc-class-ref in GraphTrendView.o


  "_CPDecimalFromFloat", referenced from:


  -[GraphStatsWindow setNewGraph] in GraphStatsWindow.o


  -[iPadGraphView viewDidLoad] in iPadGraphView.o


  -[GraphTrendView setNewGraph] in GraphTrendView.o


  "_kCPPlainWhiteTheme", referenced from:


  -[GraphStatsWindow setNewGraph] in GraphStatsWindow.o


  -[iPadGraphView viewDidLoad] in iPadGraphView.o


  -[GraphTrendView setNewGraph] in GraphTrendView.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTheme", referenced from:


  objc-class-ref in GraphStatsWindow.o


  objc-class-ref in iPadGraphView.o


  objc-class-ref in GraphTrendView.o


ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

Changing architectures between armv6 and armv7 doesn't do anything it seems

Comment: What are the exact errors that you are seeing?

Comment: edited question with error info

Comment: I changed the architecture in the target inspector from "Standard (armv6 armv7)" to "Optimized (armv7)" and now it works on my iPhone 4, but how will it behave on a 3GS, 3G, or iPad?

Comment: It will crash on those armv6 devices if your app is compiled for armv7 only. I've just encountered the same building error and am looking for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is an issue with a beta version of iOS and is therefore still covered by the NDA I'll instead point you to the Apple Dev forum where I found a solution for this:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/369315#369315

Only suggestion is to make sure that any linked libraries do not have "Build Active Architecture Only" set to YES as this will make any other multi-architecture settings you have set useless.

Comment: Since 4.3 has been released, can you post details?

Comment: The key is to ensure that the ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH (Build Active Architecture Only) setting on the linked core-plot library is set to NO. Also be careful that this is set at both the target and project level.

Comment: I'm having this same problem and this solution is not working, any suggestions?